# Trouble with using Joomla templet with XAMPP 1.7.2 which has PHP 5.3.0 in mac os x

Tags: php, macos, joomla, xampp

I am using a joomla templet with XAMPP 1.7.2 which has PHP 5.3.0 in mac os x 10.5.7
i am having lots of trouble like

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/templet01/plugins/system/tbox.php on line 98

Joomla itself is not functioning properly.

Please help.

-Daniel

Comment: Which version of Joomla do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a release of Joomla that is ready for php 5.3? If so switch to that. Or downgrade XAMPP to a version with php 5.2.X. Or not using XAMPP at all and instead using macports (note if you want php 5.2 youll have to grab the old port file and host a local repo - its not as hard as it sounds - i do it on my machine) or compile the source yourself in /usr/local or /opt.

However it may also be that simply truning off `display_errors` in your php.ini will fix the issue - or changing the error level.

Comment: macports has a php52 tree, in case you hadn't poked around lately.

Comment: i have switched to XAMPP 1.0.1 ......
this is the earlier version available on sourceforge for mac osx.....
this solves the problem ........

have another question.....
whats the reason behind XAMPP 1.0.1 to 1.7.2 for mac osx ?
i mean why no version between these two?

Comment: @Owen: Awesome. Last year when i switched from compiling my own to ports they went and upgraded it and removed 52 from the repo. Thansk for the info!

@daniel: i have no idea im not really a user of it.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 1.5.15 and up is compatible with php 5.3.

However the OpenID authentication module is not yet compatible.